# Possible to indent lines in template without also indeting the content?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Below am creating a string with newlines, and will end up in an email later on.

```
    if (action) {
      description = `
Git pull request action:        ${action}
Git pull request for repo:      ${req.body.repository.full_name}
Git pull request for repo URL:  ${req.body.repository.html_url}

Git pull request title:         ${req.body.pull_request.title}
Git pull request description:   ${req.body.pull_request.body}
Git pull request by user:       ${req.body.pull_request.user.login}
Git pull request URL:           ${req.body.pull_request.html_url}
`
    };
```

However if I indent the lines like so

```
    if (action) {
      description = `
        Git pull request action:        ${action}
        Git pull request for repo:      ${req.body.repository.full_name}
        Git pull request for repo URL:  ${req.body.repository.html_url}

        Git pull request title:         ${req.body.pull_request.title}
        Git pull request description:   ${req.body.pull_request.body}
        Git pull request by user:       ${req.body.pull_request.user.login}
        Git pull request URL:           ${req.body.pull_request.html_url}
     `
    };
```

it also indents the output.

**Question**
Is there a way to indent the lines without also indenting the output?

Comment: Don't use template literals (at least not one huge literal)

Comment: @Andreas What would the alternative be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to do that.

However there is a [TC39 proposal to change that](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-string-dedent) (Still in `draft` phase). 
So *maybe* it will be possible in the future.

In the meantime, you can use the zero-dependency [dedent library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dedent) which does exactly that.

```js
let dedent = require("dedent");

// ...

if (action) {
  description = dedent`
    Git pull request action:        ${action}
    Git pull request for repo:      ${req.body.repository.full_name}
    Git pull request for repo URL:  ${req.body.repository.html_url}

    Git pull request title:         ${req.body.pull_request.title}
    Git pull request description:   ${req.body.pull_request.body}
    Git pull request by user:       ${req.body.pull_request.user.login}
    Git pull request URL:           ${req.body.pull_request.html_url}
  `
};
```

It takes care of different types of line-breaks, empty lines, escaped back-ticks, and keeps all other indentation consistent.

Comment: Why a library? o.O Use plain old string concatenation, or put the "lines" in an array and call `.join("\n")`, ...

Comment: @Andreas It's a zero dependency library that takes care of some other cases like different types of line-breaks, empty lines, escaped back-ticks, and keeps all other indentation consistent. I don't see an issue with using that. Why re-invent the wheel? Especially when there are no dependencies, it doesn't make a big difference if you use the lib or just re-implement it's functionalities. As I said, there is more to it than a plain `.join()`.

Comment: @Andreas IMHO, from the code readability perspective, this approach is far better than using concatenation or using an array and `join()`

Comment: @Yousaf It doesn't matter what you (or I) think. Asking for a library is off-topic, hence why should an answer _"use library X"_ then be a valid answer? The hint for the tc39 proposal is nice to know, and might be an answer if browsers already support it or if there's working transpiler for it.

Comment: @NullDev Asking for a library is off-topic, hence an answer that is _"use library X"_ is not an answer in my eyes and therefor my comment.

Comment: @Andreas OP did not ask for a library. There just happened to be one which takes care of OP's problem. Hence, it isn't off-topic.

Comment: @Andreas OP didn't ask for any library and this answer not only answers the question but also shared a solution. Anyways, OP's problem has been solved and that's what matters!

Comment: I haven't said that OP did such a thing. But if asking for a library is off-topic, then answering with a library should also be "off-topic"/not an answer - at least if there are other ways to solve it, like plain old `+`

Comment: @Andreas "`then answering with a library should also be off-topic`" - Well, that's your opinion. Generally speaking, they aren't. I'm just trying to help. If you feel like my answer isn't helpful in that sense, feel free to post an answer with a vanilla-javascript approach. I'd be happy to upvote it.